# Downloading data from arcgis app dashboad

Tags: python, arcgis

How could I accces the data from the arcgis app? If I click the link, it shows a number of tables in bottom. https://ladhh.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=3b9b6f22d92f4d688f1c21e9d154cae2

if we click on **Option**, it provides an Export option. I was trying to figure out the underlying link or method to save the exported file by python script.

Answer (score -1):

I think you will need selenium for this.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

You might get it via a curl post header command. In Chrome, open the main url and open your developer tools, click network, and refresh the page, watch the header tab. It should show any POST headers, you could also right click and select to copy the link via curl command as well.